# GooglePlay64-bitRequirement

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am developing mobile app by using Nativescript with Angular.
When I uploaded my apk file on Google Play Store, it gave me the warning message as shown in below:
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
From August 1, 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
Please share me how you how to follow up to solve this problem if have some experiences with this.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Zaw Zaw Naing

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your APK or app bundle for native code. Add few line of code in your project App_Resources directory app.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml file for create app bundle.

**File Path:-** projectName -> App_Resources -> app.gradle :-

```
android {

  defaultConfig { 

    generatedDensities = []

    applicationId = "com.tcpi.tcpsales"

    ndk {
      abiFilters.clear()
    }

}

aaptOptions {

    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"

}

splits {

    abi {

      enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism

      reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string

      include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'

      universalApk true

    }

  }

}

project.ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'arm64-v8a': 2, 'x86': 3]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def baseAbiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter("ABI"), 0)

        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

            output.versionCodeOverride = baseAbiVersionCode * 100017 + variant.versionCode

        }

    }

}

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")) {

    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";

} else {

    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";

}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{

    apply from: settingsGradleFile;

}
```

**Change Version Code In Android Manifest File Like:-**

File path is projectName -> App_Resources -> src -> AndroidManifest.xml :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 
package="com.tcpi.tcpsales"
 
android:versionCode="2032"
 
android:versionName="2.32">
```